# DataFrame Python

Tags: mysql, sql, python, sintaxe, dataframe

Boa Tarde galera, estou com uma dúvida e queria pedir a ajuda de vocês. Queria saber como fazer um DataFrame em python que armazene os dados de uma view do sql e também saber como ficaria a sintaxe, obrigado.

Obs: já fiz a conexão com o banco de dados.

Aqui faço a conexão com o banco de dados, ai queria jogar a minha view dentro de uma data frame.

```
import pyodbc 
import pandas as pd

#Conexão com Sql Server
connection = pyodbc.connect("DSN=SQLServer")  

if connection:
    print ("Conectado ao SQL!\n")


try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        #Utilizando o fetchal para trazer varios registros
        sql = "SELECT * FROM dw.dbo.vW_Vendas"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        tabela = cursor.fetchall()
        print(tabela)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Comment: Ola Ytado seria bom para sua pergunta se você adicionar o código que você fez ate o momento.  Se você estiver falando de `pandas.DataFrame` talvez isso te ajude [pandas.read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html#pandas-read-sql)

Comment: Obrigado Vou dar uma olhada, adicionei o código para melhorar a pergunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM dw.dbo.vW_Vendas", connection)
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado  deu certinho